# How to merge a transparent png image with another image using PIL

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a transparent png image `foo.png` and I've opened another image with:

```
im = Image.open("foo2.png")
```

Now what I need is to merge `foo.png` with `foo2.png`.

(`foo.png` contains some text and I want to print that text on `foo2.png`)

Comment: Don't use `;` at the end of your commands in python: It's ugly...

Comment: Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2563822/13762264)

Answer (score 499, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image

background = Image.open("test1.png")
foreground = Image.open("test2.png")

background.paste(foreground, (0, 0), foreground)
background.show()
```

First parameter to `.paste()` is the image to paste. Second are coordinates, and the secret sauce is the third parameter. It indicates a **mask** that will be used to paste the image. If you pass a image with transparency, then the alpha channel is used as mask.

Check the [docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111195341/http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.paste).

Comment: To make sure the foreground contains transparency in all cases, use `foreground.convert('RGBA')` for the mask parameter.

Comment: Wow! This solution did the trick instantly two weeks ago, but now I totally forgot it already, and now I see it again, it again does the trick!

Comment: I'm getting ```ValueError: bad transparency mask```

Comment: Depending on your version, you may have to install the Python Image Library, and:'
from PIL import Image`

Comment: Amazing, you can use image as mask. But can I use vectorial images like svg?

Comment: `TypeError: paste() got an unexpected keyword argument 'alpha'`

Comment: @DenizOzger To fix `ValueError: bad transparency mask` use `bg.paste(fg, (0, 0), fg.convert('RGBA'))`

Comment: Thank you for indicating the information about the mask and the link to the documentation appreciate it.

Comment: this does not work as expected, it is not a proper overlay for a transparent image. fading transparency gives ugly results. It transparency is ON/OFF you should get what you expect though

Comment: Thank you for sharing. In my case "import Image" doesn't work. I had to use "from PIL import Image" instead.

Comment: This doesn't work.  paste() blits each channel (including alpha) using the mask as a weight, which means pasting a transparent image on top of an opaque one can cause opaque pixels to become transparent.  It just happens to work in limited cases, but it's not alpha blending.  At least 450 people have been confused by this so far, so it'd be nice to add a warning to the answer.

Comment: Thanks @MingweiSamuel, `.convert('RGBA')` is the important missing piece for lot of people it seems.

Comment: Thank you! Turns out I was missing the "secret sauce".

Answer (score 100):

`Image.paste` does not work as expected when the background image also contains transparency. You need to use real [Alpha Compositing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing).

Pillow 2.0 contains an `alpha_composite` function that does this.

```
background = Image.open("test1.png")
foreground = Image.open("test2.png")

Image.alpha_composite(background, foreground).save("test3.png")
```

EDIT: Both images need to be of the type RGBA. So you need to call `convert('RGBA')` if they are paletted, etc.. If the background does not have an alpha channel, then you can use the regular paste method (which should be faster).

Comment: I just used paste() to overlay one semi-transparent image on another, with PIL, and it worked as I expected. In what way doesn't it work as you expected?

Comment: @PeterHansen, paste() doesn't work as expected "when the background image also contains transparency".

Comment: @PeterHansen There is example: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/924#issuecomment-61848826

Comment: @homm thanks. That was so long ago I have no memory of what I tried. It seems likely I did miss the part you quoted about the background image also having transparency.

Comment: I get `ValueError: image has wrong made` as well @DenizOzger

Comment: This worked for me whereas paste was punching a "transparent hole" through my background.

Comment: `ValueError: images do not match` . Because this method works only when the image sizes are same

Comment: yup, you're right. both my bg and fg had transparency. the portion of my fg that contained color is supposed to be pasted on a transparent region of the bg. when `.paste` is used the fg becomes very grainy and off.

alpha_composite worked perfectly

Answer (score 87):

As *olt* already pointed out, `Image.paste` doesn't work properly, when source *and* destination both contain alpha.

Consider the following scenario:

Two test images, both contain alpha:

[image]
[image]

```py
layer1 = Image.open("layer1.png")
layer2 = Image.open("layer2.png")
```

Compositing image using `Image.paste` like so:

```py
final1 = Image.new("RGBA", layer1.size)
final1.paste(layer1, (0,0), layer1)
final1.paste(layer2, (0,0), layer2)
```

produces the following image (the alpha part of the overlayed red pixels is completely taken from the 2nd layer. The pixels are not blended correctly):

[image]

Compositing image using `Image.alpha_composite` like so:

```py
final2 = Image.new("RGBA", layer1.size)
final2 = Image.alpha_composite(final2, layer1)
final2 = Image.alpha_composite(final2, layer2)
```

produces the following (correct) image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the screenshots! Really helps!

Comment: But `alpha_composite` can not set the offset, would you mind to give an example to completely replace `paste` function?

Comment: I guess you would have to create a new empty image with the same size as the garget image, paste the layer at the proper position and use alpha_compositing to blend the new image over the target image.

Comment: I get: ValueError: images do not match

Comment: Images need to have the same size

Comment: Thanks so much! It fixed transparency issue I was tackling for long

Answer (score 19):

One can also use blending:

```
im1 = Image.open("im1.png")
im2 = Image.open("im2.png")
blended = Image.blend(im1, im2, alpha=0.5)
blended.save("blended.png")
```

Comment: This one ascetically worked for me. The images must have exactly the same size, but it is ok. The paste function did not quite cut it for me ...

Comment: 'ValueError: images do not match'

Comment: Possibly, they are of different dimensions. You may need to scale or crop one of those.

Comment: @Schütze see nvd's comment because he/she didn't ping (using @blahblah) you

Comment: @Schütze I had to add these lines to avoid "images do not match":

`
cloud_as_img.convert("RGBA")
cloud_as_img.putalpha(255)
cloud_as_img.save(temp_file_name)
`

Answer (score 5):

Here is my code to merge 2 images of different sizes, each with transparency and with offset:

```
from PIL import Image

background = Image.open('image1.png')
foreground = Image.open("image2.png")

x = background.size[0]//2
y = background.size[1]//2

background = Image.alpha_composite(
    Image.new("RGBA", background.size),
    background.convert('RGBA')
)

background.paste(
    foreground,
    (x, y),
    foreground
)

background.show()
```

This snippet is a mix of the previous answers, blending elements with offset while handling images with different sizes, each with transparency.

Comment: This answer doesn't appear to be quite correct. I've submitted an edit I think fixes it :)

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar question and had difficulty finding an answer. The following function allows you to paste an image with a transparency parameter over another image at a specific offset.

```
import Image

def trans_paste(fg_img,bg_img,alpha=1.0,box=(0,0)):
    fg_img_trans = Image.new("RGBA",fg_img.size)
    fg_img_trans = Image.blend(fg_img_trans,fg_img,alpha)
    bg_img.paste(fg_img_trans,box,fg_img_trans)
    return bg_img

bg_img = Image.open("bg.png")
fg_img = Image.open("fg.png")
p = trans_paste(fg_img,bg_img,.7,(250,100))
p.show()
```

Comment: `ValueError: images do not match`

Answer (score 2):

```
def trans_paste(bg_img,fg_img,box=(0,0)):
    fg_img_trans = Image.new("RGBA",bg_img.size)
    fg_img_trans.paste(fg_img,box,mask=fg_img)
    new_img = Image.alpha_composite(bg_img,fg_img_trans)
    return new_img
```

Comment: Hi, can you possibly add a little more context to your answer? Otherwise the requestor is not likely to learn the "why" behind it.

Answer (score 1):

the key code is:

```py
_, _, _, alpha = image_element_copy.split()
image_bg_copy.paste(image_element_copy, box=(x0, y0, x1, y1), mask=alpha)
```

the full function is:

```py
def paste_image(image_bg, image_element, cx, cy, w, h, rotate=0, h_flip=False):
    image_bg_copy = image_bg.copy()
    image_element_copy = image_element.copy()

    image_element_copy = image_element_copy.resize(size=(w, h))
    if h_flip:
        image_element_copy = image_element_copy.transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
    image_element_copy = image_element_copy.rotate(rotate, expand=True)
    _, _, _, alpha = image_element_copy.split()
    # image_element_copy's width and height will change after rotation
    w = image_element_copy.width
    h = image_element_copy.height
    x0 = cx - w // 2
    y0 = cy - h // 2
    x1 = x0 + w
    y1 = y0 + h
    image_bg_copy.paste(image_element_copy, box=(x0, y0, x1, y1), mask=alpha)
    return image_bg_copy
```

the above function supports:

- position(cx, cy)
- auto resize image_element to (w, h)
- rotate image_element without cropping it
- horizontal flip