# Python PIL paste with 2 png images

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have two images. The first is called `white_1.png` which is just a white background 600px, the second image is called `img2222.png` which is just black letter "A".

I would like to paste the letter A into white_1.png. however, in the ouput I only get a black background nothing else. both files are 600px. This is the code I have so far.

```
from PIL import Image

im1 = Image.open('white_1.png') 
im2 = Image.open('img2222.png')   
im1.paste(im2)

im1.save('dasdsdsad.jpg')
```

Comment: I found the answer. finally https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510313/transparent-png-in-pil-turns-out-not-to-be-transparent

Answer (score 3):

Your `img2222.png` is probably using transparency. Paste requires a mask argument if you want to use transparent pixels. If you use `paste` with no mask, it assumes transparent values as white/black pixels.

All you need to do is apply the mask to apply transparency.

`im1.paste(im2, (0, 0), im2)`

or

`im1.paste(im2,mask=im2)`

Also be aware that when you save your file as a JPG, JPG doesn't support transparency by default. Wouldn't be a problem here since you don't have any transparency at the end.

Answer (score 1):

If you shared the images you are using helping would be easier.

Just some thoughts:

- You are changing the format from .png to .jpg
- You are not expressing where the paste should be. For instance: im1.paste(im2,(0,0)).