# Python: combine two PNG files as layers

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to merge a transparant png image with another image using PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324647/how-to-merge-a-transparant-png-image-with-another-image-using-pil)

I have a couple of PNG files:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6599273/testing/image1.png
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6599273/testing/image2.png

As you can see, those images have transparent parts. When you put one on top each other they will form a nice looking image. Here, the composed image:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6599273/testing/image_composed.png

I composed the image using paint.net in a really straightforward way (drag&drop). But I need to do it programatically, using Python. And generalized to thousand of images like those (all same dimensions: 256x256 px)

How could I do it? I'm experimenting with PIL. Is it possible?

Many thanks in advance, and best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was already answered at [How to merge a transparant png image with another image using PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324647/how-to-merge-a-transparant-png-image-with-another-image-using-pil). Use the `paste` method of PIL images

Comment: Mmmm... Pretty close. By doing it in that way, I'm getting this (right part is too dark, I don't know the reason): http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6599273/testing/image_composed_test1.png

Comment: Hm, I don't have an idea then…

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the link. I'm closer now :-)