# Merging background with transparent image in PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a png image as background and I want to add a transparent mesh to this background but this doesn't work as expected. The background image is converted to transparent on places where I apply transparent mesh.

I am doing:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

map_background = Image.open(MAP_BACKGROUND_FILE).convert('RGBA')
map_mesh = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height), (0, 0, 0, 0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(map_mesh)

# Create mesh using: draw.line([...], fill=(255, 255, 255, 50), width=1)
...

map_background.paste(map_mesh, (0, 0), map_mesh)
```

But the result is:

[image]

You can see a chessboard pattern if you look carefully (used in graphics programs as no background). Transparent lines makes the background layer transparent too in places where both layers met. But I only want the transparent line to be added on top of the background.

I can solve it with:

```
map_background.paste((255,255,255), (0, 0), map_mesh)
```

but as I use different colors for different lines, I would have to make for every color this process. If I had 100 colors, then I need 100 layers what is not very good solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324647/how-to-merge-a-transparent-png-image-with-another-image-using-pil

Answer (score 11):

What you are trying to do is to composite the grid onto the background, and for that you need to use [`Image.blend`](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm#blend) or [`Image.composite`](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm#composite). Here's an example using the latter to composite red lines with random alpha values onto a white background:

```
import Image, ImageDraw, random
background = Image.new('RGB', (100, 100), (255, 255, 255))
foreground = Image.new('RGB', (100, 100), (255, 0, 0))
mask = Image.new('L', (100, 100), 0)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
for i in range(5, 100, 10):
    draw.line((i, 0, i, 100), fill=random.randrange(256))
    draw.line((0, i, 100, i), fill=random.randrange(256))
result = Image.composite(background, foreground, mask)
```

From left to right: 
 
[background]        [mask]         
[foreground]         
[result]

[image: background] [image: mask] [image: foreground] [image: composite]

(If you are happy to write the result back to the background image, then you can use one of the masked versions of [`Image.paste`](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm#Image.paste), as pointed out by [Paulo Scardine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/444036/paulo-scardine) in a deleted answer.)

Comment: there is a invisible white in the left

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble getting the above examples to work well.  Instead, this worked for me:

```
import numpy as np
import Image
import ImageDraw

def add_craters(image, craterization=20.0, width=256, height=256):

    foreground = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height), (0, 0, 0, 0))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(foreground)

    for c in range(0, craterization):
        x = np.random.randint(10, width-10)
        y = np.random.randint(10, height-10)
        radius = np.random.randint(2, 10)
        dark_color = (0, 0, 0, 128)
        draw.ellipse((x-radius, y-radius, x+radius, y+radius), fill=dark_color)

    image_new = Image.composite(foreground, image, foreground)
    return image_new
```