# Tkinter, overlay foreground image on top of a background image with transparency

Tags: python, image, tkinter, transparency

I have 2 images, in png format.
The second image, is a shape with transparent background.

**First image:**

[image]

**Second image:**

[image]

I cannot make the second image on top of the first at given coordinates (x,y) with the first image visible through the transparent zone of the second image.

**Result desired:**

[image]

```
import Tkinter
import Image, ImageTk

# open an image
head = Image.open('background2.png')
hand = Image.open('foreground2.png')
root = Tkinter.Tk()  # A root window for displaying objects

head.paste(hand,(20,20))

# Convert the Image object into a TkPhoto object
tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(head)

root.mainloop() # Start the GUI
```

An empty tk window is displayed.

Comment: You aren't adding the image to any widgets. You're going to need a label or canvas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks Bryan. 
Got it, in addition to label, the issue of transparency resolved from another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324647/how-to-merge-a-transparent-png-image-with-another-image-using-pil) (same foregound image used as a mask)

I guess, this is what cost me -2 points :-|

Now it works as expected.

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tkinter.Tk()  # A root window for displaying objects
# open image
imageHead = Image.open('head.png')
imageHand = Image.open('hand.png')

imageHead.paste(imageHand, (20, 40), imageHand)
# Convert the Image object into a TkPhoto object
tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imageHead)

panel1 = Label(root, image=tkimage)
panel1.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=E)
root.mainloop()  # Start the GUI
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys I know that I am 6 years late but I can help you with this

```
from PIL import Image

import numpy as np

# Create Image
img = Image.open("forground.png")

background = Image.open("background.png")

background.paste(img, (0, 0), img)
background.save('NewImg.png',"PNG")

NewImg = Image.open('NewImg.png')

# Use Image
tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(NewImg)

panel1 = Label(root, image=tkimage)
panel1.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=E)
root.mainloop()  # Start the GUI
```

So all you have to do is use NewImg when dealing with the file.
This code creates an image out of the two images and then utilises that image in the program.