# Python PIL: Blend transparent image onto another

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I need to blend an image over another image using Pythons PIL Library.

As you can see in the image below, my two source images are A and B.
When I do:

```
imageA.paste(imageB, (0, 0), imageB)
```

I get C as a result, but the part at the top of the gray background is now transparent. Image D is what I get when I put B over A in Photoshop and is what I need to achieve with PIL.

What am I doing wrong? How can I compose B over A in PIL to get D instead of C?

[image: Example Image]

Comment: what happens with: `imageA.paste(imageB, (0, 0), mask=imageB)`

Comment: @RickyA That should be exactly the same: the third argument to `paste` *is* the mask. Try using `imageA` as the mask instead: `imageA.paste(imageB, (0, 0), imageA)`

Comment: @Germano: That doesn't work either, image B has a drop shadow that would be cut off if I do that.

Comment: Don't use PIL, use Pillow. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15919897/5987

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. When I run `imageA.paste(imageB, (0, 0), imageB)` on some test png files it produces something similar to D. Could you post your source images (A & B) along with your full code?

Comment: What modes are the source and mask in ? Try to have them in RGBA mode for blending.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324647/how-to-merge-a-transparent-png-image-with-another-image-using-pil

Answer (score 3):

use RGBA for transparency mask

```
imageA.paste(imageB, (0, 0), imageB.convert('RGBA'))
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the best solution! The third parameter is a transparency map, but instead of creating it manually you just created it with PIL. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment for now (rep constraint).

But I think what you really need, according to your need, is to do this instead:

```
imageB.paste(imageA, (0, 0), imageA)
```

Basically, that is, make B the background image to get the desired results, because that's what I see in D.

EDIT:
Looking around more, I found this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15919897/4029893

I think you should definitely use the `alpha_composite` method, since paste doesn't work as expected for background images with transparency.