# Creating a watermark in Python

Tags: python, imagemagick, watermark

I'm trying to figure out how to create this kind of watermark, **especially the one that's in the center** (it's not an ad, it's just a perfect example of what I want to accomplish):

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can do this with PIL; the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5324647/4014959) show how to do it with a normal main image, and also how to do it properly if the main image contains transparency.

Answer (score 5):

Python's [wand](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.1/index.html) library has a [Image.watermark](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.1/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.watermark) method that can simplify common watermark operations.

```
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename='background.jpg') as background:
  with Image(filename='watermark.png') as watermark:
    background.watermark(image=watermark, transparency=0.75)
  background.save(filename='result.jpg')
```

Comment: +1 awesome code for watermarking. Is there anyway I could extract original and watermark image from the watermarked pic obtained from above code?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have python installed where I am, but it should be something like this.

```
import Image

photo = Image.open("photo.jpg")
watermark = Image.open("watermark.png")

photo.paste(watermark, (0, 0), watermark)
photo.save("photo_with_watermark.jpg")
```

[Image.paste doc](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.paste)

Comment: especially the one that's in the center

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [pyvips](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/) like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import pyvips

image = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[1], access="sequential")

text = pyvips.Image.text(sys.argv[3], dpi=700, rgba=True)

# scale the alpha down to make the text semi-transparent
text = (text * [1, 1, 1, 0.3]).cast("uchar")

# composite in the centre
image = image.composite(text, "over",
    x=int((image.width - text.width) / 2),
    y=int((image.height - text.height) / 2))

image.write_to_file(sys.argv[2])
```

Then run (for example):

```
$ ./watermark.py PNG_transparency_demonstration.png x.png "Hello world!"
```

To make:

[image]