# Image pasted with PIL produces artifacts

Tags: python, png, transparency, python-imaging-library

I have a bunch of images I need to put a text-overlay on top of. I created the overlay with GIMP (PNG with transparency) and tried pasting it on top of the other image:

```
from PIL import Image

background = Image.open("hahn_echo_1.png")
foreground = Image.open("overlay_step_3.png")

background.paste(foreground, (0, 0), foreground)
background.save("abc.png")
```

However, instead of displaying a nice black text on top, I get this:

[image: Broken Image]

overlay.png looks like this in Gimp:

[image: Overlay Gimp]

So I would expect some nice and black text instead of this colorful mess.

Any ideas? Some PIL option I am missing?

Comment: Have you tried `alpha_composite`? See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15919897/4241180)

Comment: Damn, thanks. I came from this answer but didn't scroll any further...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `vrs` pointed out above, using `alpha_composite` like this answer: [How to merge a transparent png image with another image using PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324647/how-to-merge-a-transparent-png-image-with-another-image-using-pil/15919897#15919897)

does the trick. Make sure to have the images in the correct mode (RGBA).

Complete solution:

```
from PIL import Image

background = Image.open("hahn_echo_1.png").convert("RGBA")
foreground = Image.open("overlay_step_3.png").convert("RGBA")
print(background.mode)
print(foreground.mode)

Image.alpha_composite(background, foreground).save("abc.png")
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: It sure looks like a palette problem - GIMP can't handle indexed PNG images with partial transparence - so, I'd say OP's background image is an indexed.png and PIL is forcing the overlay to indexed in a wrong way when pasting with `.paste`. I'd say that simply applying the `.convert` step on teh background would work for the OP.