# python PIL - check if image is transparent

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, transparency

I am pasting an image on another image, and after looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324647/how-to-merge-a-transparent-png-image-with-another-image-using-pil) question, I saw that in order to paste a **transparent** image, you need to do

```
background = Image.open("test1.png")
foreground = Image.open("test2.png")

background.paste(foreground, (0, 0), foreground)
```

with a **normal** image, you should do

```
background = Image.open("test1.png")
foreground = Image.open("test2.png")

background.paste(foreground, (0, 0)) // difference here
```

my question is, how can I check if an image it transparent so I can determine how to use the `paste` method (with or without the last parameter).

Answer (score 28):

I've come up with the following function as a no-dependencies solution (besides PIL of course), which takes a PIL `Image` object as an argument:

```py
def has_transparency(img):
    if img.info.get("transparency", None) is not None:
        return True
    if img.mode == "P":
        transparent = img.info.get("transparency", -1)
        for _, index in img.getcolors():
            if index == transparent:
                return True
    elif img.mode == "RGBA":
        extrema = img.getextrema()
        if extrema[3][0] < 255:
            return True

    return False
```

This function works by first checking to see if a "transparency" property is defined in the image's info -- if so, we return "True".  Then, if the image is using indexed colors (such as in GIFs), it gets the index of the transparent color in the palette (`img.info.get("transparency", -1)`) and checks if it's used anywhere in the canvas (`img.getcolors()`).  If the image is in RGBA mode, then presumably it has transparency in it, but it double-checks by getting the minimum and maximum values of every color channel (`img.getextrema()`), and checks if the alpha channel's smallest value falls below 255.

Comment: This doesn't seem to detect images that trigger PIL's "Palette images with Transparency expressed in bytes should be converted to RGBA images" error.

Comment: I added an additional conditional which seemed to catch these files: `if image.info.get("transparency", None):`

Comment: A year later: `if image.info.get("transparency", None):` resolves to false if the image file has white defined as the transparency color (`0`), so `if image.info.get("transparency", None) is not None:` is better, and obviously more properly explicit...

Comment: @BradRoot so your extra conditional would return True or False?

Comment: @moyo it should resolve to True. I've submitted an edit to this answer to include it in the code snipper. `if image.info.get("transparency", None) is not None: return True`

Answer (score 3):

I use numpy to check for alpha channel:

```
def im_has_alpha(img_arr):
    '''
    returns True for Image with alpha channel
    '''
    h,w,c = img_arr.shape
    return True if c ==4 else False
```

to use it, assuming `pil_im` is your Pillow Image:

```
import numpy as np
has_transparency = im_has_alpha(np.array(pil_im))
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the mode of the image for an alpha transparency layer. For example, RGB has no transparency, but RGBA does.

See https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/concepts.html for more.

Comment: @ghonke Thanks, fixed!

Answer (score 1):

How this function works:

- if there is an alpha channel, check the minimum alpha value
- if there is a palette, find colors containing alpha that are used in the image (they might not be)

```py
def image_is_transparent(image: Image, opaque: int = 255) -> bool:
    if 'A' in image.mode:
        # see if minimum alpha channel is below opaque threshold
        return image.getextrema()[image.mode.index('A')][0] < opaque
    if image.mode != 'P' or 'transparency' not in image.info:
        # format doesn't support transparency
        return False
    transparency = image.info['transparency']
    colors = image.getcolors()
    # check each color in the image
    if isinstance(transparency, bytes):
        # transparency is one byte per palette entry
        for _, index in colors:
            if transparency[index] < opaque:
                return True
    else:
        # transparency is palette index of fully transparent
        for _, index in colors:
            if transparency == index:
                return True
    return False
```

Comment: Nice answer. This won't work for the result of quantizing an RGBA image because there is no `transparency` key in `.info` - not sure if that's a bug in `.quantize()` though

e.g. `img = Image.new("RGBA", (100, 100), (128, 128, 128, 128)).quantize()`

Comment: (You might like to comment on this feature request! [https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/7384](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/7384))

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for there to be a difference.  If your image doesn't have an alpha channel, converting it to a mode that includes one will set it to 255 for every pixel.  If it *does* have an alpha channel already the conversion won't change anything.

```
background = Image.open("test1.png")
foreground = Image.open("test2.png")

background.paste(foreground, (0, 0), foreground.convert('RGBA'))
```