# Check if an image is transparent or not

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, transparency, image-conversion

I'm trying to check an image is transparent or not using PIL.

```
image = Image.open(file).convert('RGBA') 
alpha = image.split()[-1]
```

This gives a value like this

```
<PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=714x303 at 0x25EB0EBC040>
```

How to convert this to a transparency value? Or is this a right way to find the transparency of an image by converting it to RGBA?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do please? If you open an image and convert it to `RGBA` like that, every image you open will have a transparency channel because you added one, so it will not tell you if there was already an alpha channel before you started....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`image.getextrema()` gives the min/max ranges for each channel, so you could use that to check the range on the alpha channel:

```py
image = Image.open(file).convert('RGBA') 
alpha_range = image.getextrema()[-1]

if alpha_range == (255,255):
    print("image is not transparent")
```

Edit: did a quick search. You could also add some checks on the image mode, see the answers here too [python PIL - check if image is transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43864101/python-pil-check-if-image-is-transparent)