# Adding border to image and transforming outside the border

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, opencv

Hello I am fairly new with image transformation with Python and OpenCV, I am familiar with how to generate a border around the original image. Is there a way to transform the pixels (changing RGB values,blurring,etc.) in the "frame" of the image? I visualized this with the image below, where the grey part is the frame. My end goal would be to have the original image in the center (blue) unchanged while the grey part would consist of transformed pixels from the original image. Any input would be really helpful!

[image: Image with border]

Comment: sounds like you need to use a mask and copy only the masked area.

Comment: maybe it is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53931455/how-to-merge-a-transparent-png-image-with-another-image-using-scikit-image/53933040#53933040