# Tkinter contents of both widgets visible when overlapping

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, sprite, alpha-transparency

So, I am trying to make a video game in Tkinter (no, I don't want to use PyGame), but I have ran into a bit of a problem.

I have realized that sometimes you may want to have two widgets overlap (e.g. sprite on top of background) but have the contents of both widgets to be visible. For example, I might have a sprite with transparent sections.

How do I set the "background" option of a widget so that there is no visible background?

Note: "you can't do this" answers are acceptable.

Comment: Use canvas as it support transparent image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really posible in Tkinter. But you can set the transparency of the whole window with `root.attributes('-alpha', 0.5)`

For windows, you can do `root.attributes("-transparentcolor", "red")`, but again it will be applied to the whole window, not just the single widget.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324647/how-to-merge-a-transparent-png-image-with-another-image-using-pil) may somewhat help though.