# How to combine overlay images properly?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have three images. First, I want to add side to side two of them `home.png` (150 x 150) and `away.png` (150 x 150). These images are transparent, and I also want transparency on the output file, because I will add another image as overlay. Then, I want to add the output (300 x 150) on a center of a background image which is `red.png` (804 x 208). Also, if possible, I want to create the output file (300 x 150) without saving it on my disk. (The home logo and away logo are URLs.)

Images that will be side by side:

[image]
[image]

The background image:

[image]

The expected output:

[image]

My code so far:

```
with open("Files/home.png", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(home_logo.content) 

with open("Files/away.png", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(away_logo.content) 


image1 = Image.open('Files/home.png')
image1.show()
image2 = Image.open('Files/away.png')
image2.show()
#resize, first image
image1 = image1.resize((150, 150))
image1_size = image1.size
image2_size = image2.size
new_image = Image.new('RGB',(2*image1_size[0], image1_size[1]))
new_image.paste(image1,(0,0))
new_image.paste(image2,(image1_size[0],0))
new_image.save("Files/match.png","PNG")
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image

background = Image.open("Files/red.png")
overlay = Image.open("Files/match.png")

background = background.convert("RGBA")
overlay = overlay.convert("RGBA")

new_img = Image.blend(background, overlay, 0.5)
new_img.save("image.png","PNG")
```

The error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/emin/Documents/Match Site/test.py", line 39, in <module>
    new_img = Image.blend(background, overlay, 0.5)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2987, in blend
    return im1._new(core.blend(im1.im, im2.im, alpha))
ValueError: images do not match
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (good) questions around here. Please provide a [mre] to your problem, i.e. the full code needed to reproduce your actual problem, and provide all needed input images next to the desired output, e.g. manually drawn.

Comment: Thanks i added images and desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `overlay` image wasn't given. But, I think, for the expected output, it's not necessary at all. I basically cleaned up your code. By that, the erroneous `Image.blend` call was removed, too. (If you also want to fix that issue, kindly provide the `overlay` image.) The only things left to do were determining the proper coordinates for the `match` image inside the background image and paying attention to the transparencies.

The intermediate `match.png` doesn't need to be saved either, see the following code:

```py
from PIL import Image

# Read and resize logos
size = (150, 150)
image1 = Image.open('home.png').resize(size)
image2 = Image.open('away.png').resize(size)

# Build match image; paste both logos on an empty image
new_image = Image.new('RGBA', (2 * size[0], size[1]))
new_image.paste(image1, (0, 0))
new_image.paste(image2, (image1.size[0], 0))
# new_image.save('match.png')                   # Not necessarily needed

# Build full output; paste match image on background image w.r.t. the
# proper coordinates
background = Image.open('red.png').convert('RGBA')
bg_size = background.size
anchor = (int((bg_size[0] - 2 * size[0]) / 2), int((bg_size[1] - size[1]) / 2))
background.paste(new_image, anchor, new_image)
background.save('image.png')
```

That'd be the output:

[image: Output]

To maintain transparency of the `match` image when pasting to the background image, do not forget to properly set the `mask` parameter, cf. [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5324647/11089932).

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.8.5
Pillow:        8.1.0
----------------------------------------
```