# Pasting image with transparency leaves artifacts

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have some code like such:

```
background = Image.open("background.png").convert("RGBA")
foreground = Image.open("foreground.png").convert("RGBA")
background.paste(foreground, (0, 0), foreground)
```

For whatever reason, this adds some artifacting that I do not see in Photoshop when stacking the layers:

[pillow paste output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyDz7.jpg)

See the equivalent region/layer stacked in Photoshop here for comparison:

[photoshop layers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9Wjp.jpg)

Any idea why this is?  Should I be loading my png file differently, or saving it with max quality somehow?

Comment: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324647/how-to-merge-a-transparent-png-image-with-another-image-using-pil) seems like it has some good suggestions, do any of those work?

Comment: can you post your input images, output images as png's not jpg's. Also why do the pillow and photoshop output have different resolutions?

Comment: I just zoomed in and posted a screenshot of the lines themselves.  In any case, thank you for the thread @RandomDavis - This resolved my issue:

Image.alpha_composite(background, foreground).save("output.png", format="png")

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved with:

```
Image.alpha_composite(background, foreground).save("output.png", format="png")
```

Comment: Glad that worked. If you want your question to be more useful for other users searching for a similar issue, you might consider editing your question and adding a more detailed description of the issue - like, "jagged white lines around the border of a transparent part of an image, it looks aliased, and does not appear to have antialiasing or any partial transparency".