# Python: Cannot open converted bitmap image file, converted using PIL

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, nautilus, gnome-shell

How do I go about converting a JPG file to BMP using PIL?  Tried to use Image.open('ifile.jpg').save('ofile.bmp', 'BMP') but I get a 'bogus header data' when attempting to open the file.

Tried the copy / paste method as described in [Convert RGBA PNG to RGB with PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166400/convert-rgba-png-to-rgb-with-pil) but it does not work too.

Answer (score 1):

there is no problem in the code.(i have tried the following code and worked well.) it converts your file to desired format.

```
import Image
im = Image.open("test.bmp")
im.save("test.jpg", "JPEG")
```

i think the problem is about Ubuntu. I also met a few times and I think it is a bug. try to open with gimp...

Comment: Isn't this example backwards? The question is how to covert jpg to bmp