# Can't paste image due to ValueError: bad transparency mask

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

Creating a program to paste another image on top of another image. And when I paste a campaign logo that I made in Photoshop, And when I run the program, I get the error:

`ValueError: bad transparency mask`

I tried converting the image from RGBA to RGB, and that did not work, here is the code:

```
def test():
background = Image.open("photo.png")
logo = Image.open("66.png")

background_small = logo.resize(bg_size)
logo_small = logo.resize(logo_size)

background.paste(logo, (0, 600), logo)
background.show()

background.save('out.png')
```

Edit: I fixed the error using this stackoverflow post: [Convert RGBA PNG to RGB with PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166400/convert-rgba-png-to-rgb-with-pil)

Comment: Could you provide us with the images, so we can reproduce your error?

Comment: http://imgur.com/fZqOvEX

Comment: That is one image, but you mentioned two images. Can you provide both input images?

Answer (score 1):

Try converting both to "RGBA" first.