# Python PIL ValueError: not enough image data

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, image-conversion

I have written a function to load images (jpg, JPEG, png, gif etc.) and convert it to jpg. The code looks like this:

```
def jpg_image_open(file_path, fill_color=(255, 255, 255)):
    image = PIL.Image.open(file_path)
    print(file_path, image.mode)

    if file_path.endswith('.gif'):
        # print(image.is_animated, image.n_frames)
        for im_frame in PIL.ImageSequence.Iterator(image):
            # Converting it to RGB to ensure that it has 3 dimensions as requested
            im_frame = im_frame.convert('RGB')
            image = im_frame
            break
    elif file_path.endswith('.png'):
        image.load()

    if image.mode in ('P', 'L'):
        image.convert("RGB")
    elif image.mode in ('RGBA', 'LA'):
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/9459208/2049763
        print(file_path, " has transparency layer")
        # image.load()  # required for png.split()
        background = PIL.Image.new(image.mode[:-1], image.size, fill_color)
        background.paste(image, image.split()[-1])
        image = background
    return image, np.array(image)
```

I usually call it from other files without error.

```
# read input image as numpy array
loaded_img, in_image = create_my_tf_record_util.jpg_image_open(img_file)

PIL.Image.fromarray(in_image, 'RGB').save(out_img_file)
```

It works great for all images except, if the image is in mode  'P', 'L'.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dataset_tools/create_my_tf_record_coco.py", line 322, in thread_cube_map_annotation_png
    PIL.Image.fromarray(in_image, 'RGB').save(out_img_file)
  File "/home/mazhar/miniconda3/envs/mytfenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2554, in fromarray
    return frombuffer(mode, size, obj, "raw", rawmode, 0, 1)
  File "/home/mazhar/miniconda3/envs/mytfenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2497, in frombuffer
    return frombytes(mode, size, data, decoder_name, args)
  File "/home/mazhar/miniconda3/envs/mytfenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2430, in frombytes
    im.frombytes(data, decoder_name, args)
  File "/home/mazhar/miniconda3/envs/mytfenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 812, in frombytes
    raise ValueError("not enough image data")
ValueError: not enough image data
```

Comment: If you just want to change the extension,just `Image.open("path").save("xxx.jpg")` is okay.

Comment: Absolutely, this is most certainly overkill

Comment: I wrote it as a library. As I need the image as NumPy array, saving as JPG is just by-product. 

Initially, it was like this: Image.open("path").convert('RGB').save("xxx.jpg"). However, I was getting an error if a PNG file had a transparency layer. Thus, I need to change part of my code and it became convoluted. 

Now, I am unable to solve the issue, if it is in 'P' or 'L' mode.