# Issue converting a PNG image to a JPG image using PIL

Tags: python, pytorch, python-imaging-library, jpeg, rgba

I'm working with X-ray images to build up a neural network, using Pytorch. After some fumbling, I found my main issue was on initial loading of the images.
For example, I start with this image: [image: Image of a PNG X-ray]

When I try to load it using the ImageFolder, and then DataLoader, it shows as:
[image: Failed JPG-PNG conversion, it is just a white box.]

After looking through it, I've realised that it is PIL.show() causing the issue (and the internal PNG-JPG conversion), but for the life of me, I can't get it to work. I've tried PIL's .convert() method, with no luck, as well as the steps for copying an alpha mask onto a background as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166400/convert-rgba-png-to-rgb-with-pil?noredirect=1&lq=1), I've tried changing the background colour to black as well, and nothing, everything just degrades into the white box. I've tried it on other X-rays in the files as well, and it's the same result.

When I tried to convert an image using [PNGtoJPG.com](https://png2jpg.com/), I got this image: [image: PNGtoJPG conversion, incorrectly], but FreeConverter.com worked fine.

I know it must be something with the transparency of the original image, but at this point, I've tried everything I can find, and nothing.

For reference, this is the conversion code I've been testing on:

```
png = Image.open("0001_1297860395_01_WRI-L1_M014.png") #with the correct file path
    png.load()
    alpha = png.split()[-1]
    alpha= alpha.convert('RGBA')
    background = Image.new("RGB", png.size, (0, 0, 0))
    background.paste(png, alpha)
    background.save('./foo3.jpg', 'JPEG', quality=80)
```

The images load fine when using cv2, but since I need to use a custom transform, the method needs to convert into cv2.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm at a loss!

Comment: According to my image editor (Affinity Photo), the source is a 16bit grayscale image. According to the docs, pillow (and probably PIL, too) can't process images with more than 8bit depth per channel.

Comment: You could instead call an external tool like https://imagemagick.org/ for the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Your image is a 16-bit, greyscale PNG. You can see that with `exiftool`:

```
exiftool -BitDepth -ColorType image.png
```

**Output**

```
Bit Depth                       : 16
Color Type                      : Grayscale
```

It opens in `I` mode within PIL, i.e. as 32-bit signed integers:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('image.png')
print(im)
print(im.mode)
```

That prints:

```
<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=I size=494x727>
I
```

An easy way to make it 8-bit unsigned is convert to Numpy array, shift right 8 bits and convert to unsigned 8-bit:

```
# Make "im" into Numpy array, shift right 8 bits, convert to uint8
na = (np.array(im)>>8).astype(np.uint8)
```

Now you can make that back into PIL Image with:

```
pilImage = Image.fromarray(na)
pilImage.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'll add a transform to the neural network that does this shift and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

The individual image conversion can be handled by using
`png.point(lambda x: x / 256)`
This is documented here: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/6765, where it's shown that PIL has issues with PNGs. However, the issue of it not carrying through the neural network is still an issue, but better suited for another question.