# How to compose an image with an alpha channel over another image(RGB, without alpha channel)? Using python PIL

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, rgba

My question is similar as this one:
[With the Python Imaging Library (PIL), how does one compose an image with an alpha channel over another image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374878/with-the-python-imaging-library-pil-how-does-one-compose-an-image-with-an-alp/3375291#3375291)
I have two images, the top image with alpha channels and the bottom one without. I want to put top image over the bottom one, resulting in a new image , just as would occur if they were rendered in layers. I would like to do this with the Python PIL. Any suggestion would be appreciable, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried Kris Kowal's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3376602/355230) to the linked question?

Answer (score 1):

Simply extend your RGB image to RGBA with A set to "1":

```
rgba = np.dstack((rgb, np.ones(rgb.shape[:-1])))
```

and then use the compose method you mentioned.

If you use [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.x/reference/Image.html) instead you can simply use:

```
imRGB.putalpha(alpha)
composite = PIL.Image.alpha_composite(imRGB, im2RGBA)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue by myself, the problem is that the value of alpha channel in RGBA image is either 0 or 255, I just change the 255 to 220, so that the top image won't cover the bottom image. My code is as follow:

```
def transPNG(srcImageName, dstImageName):
img = Image.open(srcImageName)
img = img.convert("RGBA")
datas = img.getdata()
newData = list()
for item in datas:
    if item[0] > 200 and item[1] > 200 and item[2] > 200:
        newData.append(( 255, 255, 255, 0))
    else:
        newData.append((item[0], item[1], item[2], randint(220, 220)))
img.putdata(newData)
img.save(dstImageName,"PNG")
```